# Mutation equivalence of quivers

Tags: rt.representation-theory, quivers, cluster-algebras

Given two orientations $Q, Q'$ of a Dyinkin diagram. Is it always true that after a sequence of mutations, $Q$ becomes $Q'$? Are the some references about this? Thank you very much.

Comment: Maybe you should rather read carefully the original articles of Fomin and Zelevinsky, and come back here later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's true for any two acyclic quivers with the same underlying diagram having different orientations. See [lectures notes on cluster algebras](http://bookzz.org/book/2324891/6e1fab) by Robert Marsh.